# Execute any bash command, get the results of stdout/stderr immediatly and use stdin

Tags: process, rust, output, exec

I would like to execute any bash command. I found `Command::new` but I'm unable to execute "complex" commands such as `ls ; sleep 1; ls`. Moreover, even if I put this in a bash script, and execute it, I will only have the result at the end of the script (as it is explain in the process doc). I would like to get the result as soon as the command prints it (and to be able to read input as well) the same way we can do it in bash.

Comment: What do you mean by "and to be able to read input as well"?

Comment: I mean, if you launch a program from the command line : `./myprog`, very often the program waits for you to enter some data, for instance, if its a command line game, it may ask a number. When I use Command::new(), it instantly terminates it if they is a rust `read_line` for example. No time to enter anything. I mean I really want to act like I executed the program from the command line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Command::new` is indeed the way to go, but it is meant to execute a program. `ls ; sleep 1; ls` is not a program, it's instructions for some shell. If you want to execute something like that, you would need to ask a shell to interpret that for you:

```
Command::new("/usr/bin/sh").args(&["-c", "ls ; sleep 1; ls"])
// your complex command is just an argument for the shell
```

To get the output, there are two ways:

- the [`output`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.output) method is blocking and returns the outputs and the exit status of the command.
- the [`spawn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.spawn) method is non-blocking, and returns a handle containing the child's process `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` so you can communicate with the child, and a [`wait`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Child.html#method.wait) method to wait for it to cleanly exit. Note that by default the child inherits its parent file descriptor and you might want to set up pipes instead:

You should use something like:

```
let child = Command::new("/usr/bin/sh")
                .args(&["-c", "ls  sleep 1 ls"])
                .stderr(std::process::Stdio::null()) // don't care about stderr
                .stdout(std::process::Stdio::piped()) // set up stdout so we can read it
                .stdin(std::process::Stdio::piped()) // set up stdin so we can write on it
                .spawn().expect("Could not run the command"); // finally run the command

write_something_on(child.stdin);
read(child.stdout);
```

Comment: Thank you, I commented the lines containing `piped()` or `null()` because I want to use the parent's file descriptors.

Comment: Since `Command` follows the builder pattern, it's a bit more idiomatic to structure it like this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=37194d432ecb64c32d5fc5e59937570e&version=stable&backtrace=0

Comment: @NateMara Actually I initially wrote https://gist.github.com/2c21ce9e7b919b30cb1444548dc897d9, and was quite surprised it takes `&mut self` instead of `self`. Anyway you are right, I'll edit my answer, thanks.

Comment: I think most builders use `&mut self`.

Comment: Maybe, I haven't really been paying attention to that. With `self` there is a huge possibility that people not paying attention would write `builder.foo(); builder.bar();` ignoring the result so that might be the reason. This could be solved with a `must_use` annotation though. Don't know, I was just surprised there for a moment.