# How can I run multiple commands in same subprocess?

Tags: rust

I am trying to execute a sequence of commands in the same process. E.g.

```
let v = vec!["python3 -m venv venv", "source venv/bin/activate"];
```

I have tried joining the vector with " && " and using the [`.args`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.args) method to no avail. I.e.

```
std::process::Command::new("python3")
    .args(&["-m", "venv", "venv", "&&", "source", "venv/bin/activate"])
    .output()
    .expect("failed to execute command");
```

What is the best way to do this?

**Note**: I want to do this all in the same process to use the Python virtual env that is activated.

Comment: If you want to use shell syntax you need to invoke a shell.

Comment: @CodesInChaos doh! If you write up an answer I'll accept it... Otherwise will self-answer and leave this up for reference.

Comment: There is probably a better solution not involving a shell. And "in the same process" looks wrong to me, but I'll leave that to somebody with better unix knowledge than me.

Comment: It would be better to mark this as a duplicate of an existing question (if one exists). I found [Execute any bash command, get the results of stdout/stderr immediatly and use stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38551500/execute-any-bash-command-get-the-results-of-stdout-stderr-immediatly-and-use-st) and [Execute a shell command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31666936/execute-a-shell-command) that look like candidates. (One answer to the second one suggests using `Result::and_then` in Rust to emulate `&&` in the shell, which strikes me as the best idea.)

Comment: @trentcl good finds - voting to close this as dupe... It strikes me that the `Result::and_then` call would occur after the process has exited.

Comment: Yes, that's what a shell would do, too. I don't know if "reusing" the subprocess is really a thing that you *can* do. Isn't it gone when the first command terminates?

Comment: @trentcl AFAIK that is correct.

Comment: Note that all that `activate` does is to set an environment variables (`VIRTUAL_ENV`), prepend `$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin` to the `PATH` and unset `PYTHON_HOME`, which you can do yourself before calling your main command (I'd post an answer, except that the question is closed…)

Comment: @Jmb Yeah but that doesn't help with this problem... manually setting the environment variables would still need to be done in the same process (before the other commands are executed).

Comment: @Alex This can be done with [Command::env](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.env) for a single command or with [std::env](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/env/index.html) for the current process (and therefore for all its future children).